# Poor performance in Snap.svg with lots of elements

Tags: snap.svg

I'm looking to animate a lot of elements using Snap.svg.

I am creating a visualization backed by a model. For this reason, I'm not bothering to use `Snap.animate`, but am instead just setting the positions of each element on every `animationFrame`.

To move each element, I loop through my list of elements and call `el.transform`.

When I start needing to transform more than a couple hundred elements, this process starts to take a very long time.

Two example Fiddles show this:

1. http://jsfiddle.net/zfw78n85/: Uncomment the line setting `totalCircles = 500`
2. http://jsfiddle.net/9o0qswsb/: Notice how, after a few seconds, the `setInterval` timer starts taking over a second, and eventually it takes 10 or more seconds.

I'm assuming that the issue is because it's trying to modify the DOM many times between each `requestAnimationFrame`. Looking at the timeline in Chrome appears to confirm this -- I see lots of calls to `render` in each frame.

Is there a way to make this more efficient? Maybe to batch up all the transformations so that we only update the DOM once?

Comment: Using animationFrame here is not an ideal choice with that code (or rather than code is not a great choice with raf). Reason being that as you add more elements, the processing time will take longer, which means raf will be called later, which means it will slow down. Normally you would want to take into account the time taken since last update and move a relative delta to that (which Snap and other animators will take into account). So it's natural it will slow down first and foremost. There may be other issues in there, but I'm wary of trying to fix the wrong approach.

Comment: It production code I would certainly look at the time delta, but the point here is specifically the increase in time, so this code highlights that. The point is that calling `element.transform(m)` many times takes a very, very long time, even though it should theoretically be possible to update a few hundred DOM nodes at once without it taking so long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of issues really. I feel like the approach is firstly, a bit wrong, but ultimately I don't know the larger project or picture.

Firstly, the reasons libraries like Snap exist is to make SVG easier, rather than faster. They will take into account things like how long it was since the last requestAnimationFrame, and move an element according to that delta (otherwise it will slow down and speed up whatever even if just a bit, maybe you will be ok with that). So if you aren't using that AND you are bothered about performance, it feels  a bit like you may be choosing the wrong library. However, there may be other goodness you need, so I'm writing what I would possibly do.

So if we look at the example, one of the places that will slow this down, is creating matrices or examining existing transforms etc. If there is just one bit, that's called repeatedly, it may be better to go native with that.

So you could change the movefunc to be something like the following (store the data with data() for reuse next cycle), then set the translate skipping any extra library methods.

```
function moveCircle(circ) {
  circ.data('x', circ.data('x')+1 || 1);
  circ.node.setAttribute('transform', 'translate('+circ.data('x')+')')
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9o0qswsb/8/)

You will probably find this performs a bit better, but again, may slow/speed up, depending on what the system is doing. This may be desired, if you always want an exact increment for some reason.

Edit: The main reason transform will be slower is that behind the scenes it does extra helper functions. For example I think it calculates a bounding box, in case you want to rotate about the center (e.g 'r90' would do this, as Snap by default does this to help you, as most people want to rotate around the center). I think there's certainly an argument for avoiding extra helper stuff if you pass it proper svg transforms eg 'translate(20,20)', but there may still be extra processing to break that all down, even if not as much.

If I was doing this a lot, I may be tempted to write my own native attr plugin, something like, w...

```
Snap.plugin( function( Snap, Element, Paper, global ) {
    Element.prototype.nativeAttrs = function( attrs ) {
        for (var p in attrs)
            this.node.setAttributeNS(null, p, attrs[p]);
        return this;
    }
});   

circ.nativeAttrs({ 'transform': 'translate('+circ.data('x')+')'});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9o0qswsb/17/)

Comment: This is a great answer. Re-calculating local transforms is actually not a problem in my code -- I shouldn't have added that to the jsFiddle, my code looks at the model's x and y. However, the most striking performance gain is using `circ.node.setAttribute('transform', 'translate('+circ.data('x')+')')` instead of `circ.transform("t"+circ.data('x')+","+circ.data('y'))`. See this updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9o0qswsb/9/. This is using the same caching in `data` as you do, but it uses Snap's transform string. This starts failing very early. Do you know the reason for the difference?

Comment: ... or, just as strikingly, the difference between `circ.node.setAttribute('transform', translation) ` and `circ.attr({transform: translation})`. I would have thought that `attr` should basically be doing the same thing as `node.setAttribute`, but clearly not. See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9o0qswsb/11/

Comment: I've added a bit of extra info to the bottom of the answer about that.

Comment: Awesome, thank you. Without making a jsPerf about it, is `setAttributeNS` significantly faster than `setAttribute`?

Comment: I really don't know, but I assume there's not a lot of difference, and I think you can use either (unless you need a namespace like for xlink).